# Setting up multiple sites on IIS and adding SSL - GCP Virtual Machine

Tags: ssl, iis, google-cloud-platform

Newbie in IIS/Networking
I have an Instance on GCP with IIS, have installed Multiple sites , trying to add SSL to each site,  this worked fine for first site, but for second i would need additional IP address, Created alias IP address on console, but these IP address are not reflecting in IPconfig of server, any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

> Created alias IP address on console

[image]

---

> IP address are not reflecting in IPconfig

[image]

Comment: https://www.jexusmanager.com/en/latest/tutorials/https-binding.html#background What's the Windows Server version you use? For Windows Server 2012 and above, you can use only a single IP address. All HTTPS bindings can use SNI.

Answer (score 0):

You have different ways to do this but the most common one will be to configure the [host header](https://www.digicert.com/ssl-support/ssl-host-headers-iis-8.htm) (also known as domain names or hostnames), that is going to allow you to have more than one site assigned to a single IP.

You need to follow these steps to enable HTTPS in the site:

1) Create SSL certificate request file

2) Install certificate in IIS

3) Add HTTPS Binding

[Here](https://www.digicert.com/csr-ssl-installation/iis-8-and-8.5.htm) you have a good example in how to install SSL certificates in IIS.